# ReactNative switch statement with class Comopnent

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm working on react native expo project, i'm trying to reassign value to state on class component on  componentDidMount() using switch statement i 6 user journey so this is why i cant not use if statement

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    
    this.state.accessToken = await token.get();
  
    // Setp Global State
    
      let finalSteps = 1;
      
      switch(finalSteps){
        (case accessToken ? && this.props.navigation.getParam('search_type') == 3 )
        { return finalSteps = 11}
        
        case ( accessToken ? && this.props.navigation.getParam('requestType') == 1) {
          finalSteps = 6
         }
       ...
        case (!accessToken) {
           finalSteps = 3
         }
      } 
     
      dispatch(setDefaultStepsNumber(finalSteps))
      
  }
```

is the switch statement right way on my code switch(final Steps) i have too many condition each one i want return different value of finalSteps ? it seems the is syntax error

Comment: i think problem is from returning value in componentDidMount, try to use break instead

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `switch case` in above scenario since your conditions are not depend on the value of a single key. In these situations, you can use conditional (ternary) operator to assign values like below

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const accessToken = await token.get();
    let finalSteps = 1;
    if (!accessToken) finalSteps = 3
    else {
      finalSteps = this.props.navigation.getParam('search_type') == 3 ? 11
        : this.props.navigation.getParam('requestType') == 1 ? 6
          : 1 // all other conditions like above
    }
    dispatch(setDefaultStepsNumber(finalSteps))
  }
```